# 64 bit vs. 32 bit - Significantly longer time to attach the debugger 

Tags: development, debugging

Since switching to a 64-bit dev environment on Sharepoint 2007, I've noticed it takes orders or magnitude longer to attach the Visual Studio debugger to the OOTB SharePoint assemblies and my custom assemblies.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Can you please update with more detail such as how you're doing it and at what point you have to wait? E.g. "As soon as I click the Attach button in the Attach To Process dialog"

Comment: I'm using 64-bit and also 32-bit live windows servers to devel sharepoint apps. but I don't have your problem, there is not diff. when attaching to debuger. So yes, more details are required.

Answer (score 2):

Does it have internet access, maybe on this machine you are hitting the clr check issue on this server

- [A new approach to solve SharePoint’s painfully slow spin-up / start-up time for first request](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/04/new-approach-to-solve-sharepoints.html)

Also could be just a bit under spec'd as 64 bit will use more memory etc than a 32 bit so could be running out of physical mempory and swapping out perhaps which might be slower but then it would likely be slower for other tasks too.